# SyntaxError using input() to get a path

Tags: python, syntax-error

I had a function, which needs the path to a file, working last week, but when I needed it today it gave me an error, and I can't figure out what is not working, though it should be pretty simple. See :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import fonctions
print('\n\n')

directory = input("file path : ")

hdulist=pyfits.open(directory)
```

This is only the beginning of my function, and when I use it, it asks for the path, I write one, and it gives me this :

```
file path : /Users/geoffroysarrazin/Desktop/stage_observatoire/casa.fits
File "<string>", line 1
/Users/geoffroy/Desktop/stage/casa.fits
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I believe I have changed something since the last time I used it but can't remember what, and it's quite frustrating because the error seems to be simple/obvious...
Any idea...?

Sorry, I forgot : Python 2.7.5, OSX 10.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))`. If you're using python 2, you'll want to use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

```
directory = raw_input("file path : ")
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I can remember now what has changed since the last time I used this : I had to install Python 2.7 whereas I was on Python 3...
Thanks for the help